Powering STM32WB55 with Alkaline Batteries
I am designing a portable device based on the STM32WB55 with alkaline batteries as a power source. I want to use either AAs or AAAs as they are more readily available for the average user. In terms of size constraints, I can fit up to 4 AAAs (preferably 3 or less) or up to 3 AAs (preferably 2 or less).
My device heavily leverages the low-power modes of the MCU. I am using external interrupts (i.e. push buttons) to wake-up the STM32, run some processes for a second or two, then enter back into a sleep state.
For peripherals, I have an Accelerometer and a LoRa chip. The accelerometer uses <1 mA in all cases. The LoRa chip uses ~1 µA current during sleep and will momentarily draw up to 118 mA to transmit after an interrupt. The LoRa module is never used to receive signals, so it is almost always in sleep.
From my understanding, alkaline batteries are nominally 1.5 V/cell but can be up to 1.7 V when fully charged under no load and down to 0.9 V when fully depleted. Given this information, I understand my options for voltage input from the batteries to be as follows:

Single-cell: 0.9-1.7 V (1.5 V nominal)
Dual-cell: 1.8-3.4 V (3.0 V nominal)
Triple-Cell: 2.7-5.1 V (4.5 V nominal)
Quad-Cell: 3.6-6.8 V (6.0 V nominal)

My STM32 and Accelerometer have an operating range of 1.71-3.6 V while the LoRa chip operates at 1.8-3.7 V. Both the STM32 and LoRa have an internal LDO and DC-DC Converter. The internal LDOs are max 200mV dropout.
Question 1: If I went with a dual-cell design, can I power the entire device directly from the alkaline batteries without any voltage regulation circuits? If so, are there any major consequences or considerations I should know about?
Question 2: Since my device incorporates components with a wide range of frequencies (LoRa @ 915 MHz, BLE @ 2.4 GHz, HSE @ 32 MHz, LSE @ 32.768 kHz), would a DC-DC regulator (buck/boost converter) produce switching frequencies that would be difficult to filter out?

how are you powering the peripherals?

I was intending to use the same power source for all components (peripherals + MCU).
Accelerometer and STM32 both have an operating range of 1.71V ~ 3.6V, while the LoRa is 1.8V ~ 3.6V.

You could also consider Lithium-ion batteries 10440, same size as AAA batteries. Or 14500, 16340... They have 3.7V nominal, with a range 4.2V ~ 3V. One single battery and an LDO would be sufficient. For small currents and small voltage difference, I think that an LDO would be more efficient and simple than a buck converter. And less noisy.

Answer to question 1: Yes, you can make all your devices run with this power domain BUT you need to consider about current not just voltage. Radio modules draws so much currents while transmitting. So if you seek for advice, I do not recommend you to go with this setup. Even if it works probably it won't last long. You may choose li-ion batteries instead like Gos mentioned.
Answer to question 2: Yes, switching frequencies may be a little headache while using Buck/Boost converters. If you have not so much power drop you may use LDO. But again think about currents because LDOs are not ideal for high currents.
